# How can I get a value from select using a button in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a button in my code:

```
<div class="content" data-role="content" id="content" >
         <div id="car">
            <select name="selectCar" class="span12" id="Options"  >
            <option value="-1">Bir istasyon seçiniz.</option>
            <option value="1">Mimarlık</option>
            <option value="2">Yurtlar</option>
            <option value="3">Bilgisayar Mühendisliği</option>
            <option value="4">Kimya Mühendisliği</option>
            <option value="5">Rektörlük</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div id="cinfo"></div>

       <button onclick="javascript:callCarInfo(this);">Call PodCar</button>
</div>
```

When I click the button, I want to send the value from the `<select>` element to my function. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What does `callCarInfo` do?

Comment: what have you tried already? how does your attempt for `callCarInfo` look like?

Comment: You need to update this with your actual JavaScript code.  You also need to get in the 21st century and use [events.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `function.call` to send the value. I am sure about the practical purpose of why yuo want to do that. You can even directly access the value of the select inside the function.

<kbd>[Func.Call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)</kbd>

**http://jsfiddle.net/8a3zJ/**

```
<button onclick="javascript:callCarInfo.call(this,document.getElementById('Options').value);">Call PodCar</button>

function callCarInfo(arg)
{
    alert(arg);
}
```

Here `this` inside the function will be the button context itself and `arg` will have your dropdown selected value.

Comment: With call you can get the `this` context as the clicked button .

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get the selected option when you click your button.

Try this function:

```
 function callCarInfo()
 {
     alert($('#Options :selected').val());
 }
```

Here's a live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ytTx/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: My answer works, solve the OP's issue. Why some one voted down?

Comment: Ask first if the OP wants to use jQuery. Only *then* answer *with* jQuery, please.

Answer (score 0):

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/GC7Rj/)

```
function callCarInfo(obj) {
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var span12 = document.getElementsByClassName('span12')[0];

    obj.innerHTML = span12.value;
}
```